# API to create user with realm set as http-sso?

Tags: devops, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I tried below 2 API's to create a user in Artifactory. However, even when I provide "http-sso" as the realm in the payload, the user's realm is set as internal. Is there an API to create a user with the realm set as "http-sso"?

```
POST https://<artifactory>/artifactory/api/users

POST https://<artifactory>/artifactory/access/api/v2/users
```